# How to click an element in xpath and selenium having option-id element but same div class?

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

I have the following html code snippet.

```
<div class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">
    <div class="swatch-option color" option-type="1" option-id="49" option-label="Black" option-tooltip-value="#000000" "="" style="background: #000000 no-repeat center;"></div>
    <div class="swatch-option color" option-type="1" option-id="52" option-label="Gray"  option-tooltip-value="#8f8f8f" "="" style="background: #8f8f8f no-repeat center;"></div>
    <div class="swatch-option color" option-type="1" option-id="57" option-label="Purple"  option-tooltip-value="#ef3dff" "="" style="background: #ef3dff no-repeat center;"></div>
</div>
```

I want to click the first option (`option-id="49" option-label="Black"`) through `Selenium` and `Java` but not sure how to do that. This is what I tried and I got following exception.

```
driver.findElement(By.className("swatch-option color"));
```

**Exception:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted.
*** Element info: {Using=class name, value=swatch-option color}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByClassName(RemoteWebDriver.java:477)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByClassName.findElement(By.java:391)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
    at com.radial.webstore.CheckoutFlowFunctionalTest.testCheckoutScenario(CheckoutFlowFunctionalTest.java:33)


Results :

Tests in error: 
  CheckoutFlowFunctionalTest.testCheckoutScenario:33 » InvalidSelector invalid s...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css selectors like:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".swatch-option.color")).click();
```

Or xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='swatch-option color']")).click();
```

Of course you could get selectors based on other attributes, here are some examples with css:

```
.swatch-option.color[option-id=49]

.swatch-option.color[option-label=Black]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several css ways you can do this. Since, you want to select the element with option-label='Black' try either

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.swatch-attribute-options.clearfix > div[option-label='Black']"));
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[option-label='Black']"));
```

One of the above codes may work.

Comment: the selector from your first option might return any element :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.swatch-option.color"))
```

This will give you the list of options you desire

Hope this help!